# Remove "\" (backslash) from String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have the following code:

```
let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()

var encriptat3: String = "ope=sql&para=UPDATE xw_usuarios SET IDFIREBASE = '" + refreshedToken! + "' where USUARIO = '" + self.usuari + "'"
encriptat3 = encriptat3.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
```

And the final value of my string is :

```
"ope=sql&para=UPDATE xw_usuarios SET IDFIREBASE = \'XXXXXXX\' where USUARIO = \'99997\'"
```

And my ask is : How I can remove the "\" from my ending value and build my url correctly?

Currently I'm using Swift 2.3. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the backslashes are part of the actual string itself and not just part of how it's displayed to you (to indicate that the `'`s are escaped)?

Answer (score 3):

swift 3

```
let string1 = "ios\\programmer"
let string2 = string1.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
print("string2 --%@",string2);
```

Comment: Please help for remove only single backslash from string

Comment: @PradeepBishnoi The code in this answer does only remove one backslash. `string1` only contains one backslash. In Swift, a backslash in a string literal must be escaped by adding an another backslash. If you do `print("\\")` then the output will be \ (a single backslash).

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.7+ :

```
let value = "Some \\value with \\backslashes."
value.replacing("\\", with: "") // Some value with backslashes.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to substitute the backslashes with an alternative, as an illustration:

```
 let string2 = string1.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

To eliminate any ambiguity arising from the need to escape a backslash within a regular string literal with yet another backslash, we can resort to an expanded string delimiter such as  #"  and  "#  .

```
let string2 = string1.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\"#, with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let aString = "ope=sql&para=UPDATE xw_usuarios SET IDFIREBASE = \'XXXXXXX\' where USUARIO = \'99997\'"
let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
```

**EDIT:**

Which version of Xcode are you using? Did you import Fondation?

```
let aString = "ope=sql&para=UPDATE xw_usuarios SET IDFIREBASE = \'XXXXXXX\' where USUARIO = \'99997\'"

let newString = (string as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\", withString: "")
```

Comment: Not working for me, Error: String has no member replacingOccurrences.

Answer (score -1):

```
var val = your string

val = val.replacingOccurrences(of: "your replace string here(like \,)", with: "")
```