# How to remove backslash from JSON string using object mapper

Tags: json, swift, objectmapper

Here is the code of getting Json string from object using object mapper:

```
let jsonString = Mapper().toJSONString(freechargeRequest)
```

but the output is coming with backslash as follows:

> "{\"region\":\"http:\/\/testrm.getquickride.com:8080\/dishaapiserver\/qr_freecharge_failure.do\",\"merchantId\":\"8mILp0KGOdEG57\",\"productInfo\":\"auth\",\"mobile\":\"1357924680\",\"channel\":\"IOS\",\"amount\":\"200\",\"surl\":\"http:\/\/testrm.getquickride.com:8080\/dishaapiserver\/qr_freecharge_success.do\",\"merchantTxnId\":\"510420180705115938\"}"

I wanted the output without backslashes in JSON string.

Comment: Possibly Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957460/remove-backslash-from-string-in-swift

Comment: @AhmadF I tried using that but didn't workout

Comment: Most likely the backslashes are virtual to be able to `print` double quotes within a literal string.